# Create a simple Lua .txt Database with write() and read()

Tags: lua, text-database

im trying to create a simple 2 functions text-file "database" with LUA. All i need is 2 Functions.

my db should look like that:

```
    varName;varValue 
    JohnAge;18 
    JohnCity;Munich 
    LarissaAge;21
    LarissaCity;Berlin
```

In fact im not stuck to any format! I just don't have a way to save data longterm in my lua enviroment and i need to find a workaround. So if you already have a 
similiar solution at hand, please feel free to throw it at me. Thank you very much

```
Function WriteToDB(varName, varValue) 
If database.text contains a line that starts with varName 
replace whatever comes after seperator ";" with varValue (but dont go into the next line)


Function ReadFromDB(varName)
If database.text contains a line that starts with varName 
take whatever comes after the seperator ";" and return that (but dont go into the next line)
elseif not found print("error")
```

Comment: I suggest you use Lua code as your format so that you can load it with a simple dofile.

Comment: hello Ihf, thanks for the quick answer. I researched a bit and i don't really see how to apply this on my problem. Do you have a small example? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Save the data as Lua code that builds a table:

```
return {
JohnAge = 18,
JohnCity = "Munich",
LarissaAge = 21,
LarissaCity = "Berlin",
}
```

Or better yet

```
return {
["John"] = {Age = 18, City = "Munich"},
["Larissa"] = {Age = 21, City = "Berlin"},
}
```

Load the data with

```
db = dofile"db.lua"
```

Access the data with

```
print(db["Larissa"].Age)
```

or

```
print(db[name].Age)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean solution! I already upvoted you yet its not shown before i reach a certain reputation threshold! Sadly it seems that my enviroment has dofile blocked to prevent abuse, yet this still seems to be the cleanest way to handle a small database. Thank you